# How do I output an unsigned char* to file without reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, unsigned

I have an `unsigned char*` filled with characters not just ASCII for example: `

```
¤ÝkGòd–ùë$}ôKÿUãšj@Äö5ÕnE„_–ÄŠç•§-ö—RS^HÌVÄ¥U`  .
```

If I `reinterpret_cast`, I'll lose characters if I'm not mistaken because they're not all ASCII. I've searched everywhere but all the solutions require some sort of casting or conversion that will alter the data. Here's what I have, which doesn't work.

```
unsigned char* cipherText = cipher->encrypt(stringTest);
string cipherString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipherText));  //<-- At this point data changes in debugger
outputfile.open(outfile);       
outputfile.close();
```

Comment: `encrypt` doesn't tell you the length of the encrypted output? What if a NUL character is part of the encrypted result?

Comment: You clearly misunderstand what `reinterpret_cast` actually does. A cast does not alter the data, it merely returns a pointer that is a different data type than the original but otherwise still points at the same memory address.  Your problem has nothing to do with casting itself. When you assign `cipherText` to a `string` as a `char*` by itself, it gets truncated on the first null encountered. You need to pass the actual byte count of `cipherText` to the `string` constructor to avoid that.

Comment: you just need to put the length of the data in the string constructor along with the pointer.

Comment: I added a comment in the code, if reinterpret_cast is fine, then how come the value inside the string is different from that of cipherText in the debugger

Comment: @Praetorian I can get the length. How should I use that to my benefit?

Comment: `std::string cipherString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipherText), the_length);` <-- without `the_length`, `std::string::string(const char*)` has to assume the pointer addresses a NUL-terminated buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling the [`string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you should be calling. Instead of the one that takes a single `char *` argument, you should call the one that takes  two arguments - a `char *` and length.

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              size_type count,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

To use it in your example

```
unsigned char* cipherText = cipher->encrypt(stringTest);
size_t cipherTextLength = // retrieve this however the API allows you to
string cipherString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipherText), cipherTextLength);

outputfile.open(outfile);       
// assuming outputfile is an ofstream
outputfile << cipherString;
outputfile.close();
```

Note that the debugger might still indicate a truncated string depending on how it's interpreting the `string`'s contents. If you open the output file in an editor and inspect the bytes you should see the expected result.

As [RemyLebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) mentions in the comments, if you don't need the `std::string` for any other purpose, you don't even need to create it, just write to the `ofstream` directly.

```
outputfile.open(outfile);       
outputfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipherText), cipherTextLength);
outputfile.close();
```

Comment: The alternative is to not create a `string` at all, but instead pass `cipherText` as-is to the `ofstream` directly: `outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipherText), cipherTextLength);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course, that's a much better idea. I'm going to steal that :)

Comment: Wow, I was completely on the wrong tracks. Thanks a lot. One more thing if I could ask, how would you read from the file?

Comment: @atsay714 `istream` has an analogous [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) that performs unformatted input.

Comment: @atsay714, I suggest writing the length of the cipher text first before writing the cipher text. That will fix the problem of reading the text back. You read the length first and then the text.

Comment: @R Sahu Well, sometimes I'm given just the text file, and I have to read it in to decrypt it.

Comment: @atsay714 If all that file contains is the encrypted data then you should be able to figure out the number of bytes by using `seekg`, `tellg` etc.

Comment: I'm still having trouble, so I made a new topic to continue if you would like to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813644/how-to-read-non-ascii-characters-from-a-text-file